# How would I convert to linkedhashmap to a java type?

Tags: scala

I am using a java API that requires a linkedhashmap

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Should I just use the scala version and then convert it somehow?

I created my mutable map:

val l = mutable.LinkedHashMapString,String

And I am trying to convert it using:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

l.asJava
```

I am getting the error:

```
[error]  found   : java.util.Map[String,String]
[error]  required: java.util.LinkedHashMap[String,String]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Java collections have a constructor that lets you create them from another collection.

`new LinkedHashMap[String, String](l.asJava)`

You could also fold your scala collection into a java one explicitly

`l.foldLeft(new java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, String]){(acc, x) => acc.put(x._1, x._2); acc}`